# I can't seem to get my JavaScript to do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I link it to an external .js file I've made to put all of my JavaScript in?

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sweet Dreams Bakery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

I've made the .js files for each page and they are in the same folder as the html files, however when I try to link them together with `<script src="home.js"</script>` underneath the library path, nothing works. I'm wanting to start with a simple image change on hover with my logo.

I've also tried the inline trick within my HTML for the logo with this code:

```
<img src="1" onmouseover="this.src='2'" onmouseout="this.src='1'">
```

I've tried linking to the "home.js" file I created and adding this into that file:

```
$(function(){
  $("#swaplogo").on({
   mouseenter: function(){
    $(this).attr('src','Logo1.png');
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    $(this).attr('src','Logo.png');
  }
  });

});
```

I thought this was supposed to call out to the id that I gave the image and all of my images are together and working fine within the site. The id code for my logo is this:

```
<img id="swaplogo" alt="sweet dreams bakery logo" src="Logo.png" >
```

How would I go about linking an external JavaScript file (like my CSS files) to the html page in order to get the interactions to function correctly?

How to I link to my JavaScript to begin with? and then how do I make my image change on hover/mouseover?

Comment: Do you have JS disabled ? open browser console and reload the page to see if you get any kind of errors

Comment: Using a `<script src="filename.js">` tag is correct. Use your browser's developer tools to check whether the server is returning a "not found" error; there may be a problem with the way you're publishing your code to your server.

Comment: To link an external JS file, you need to include another script tag either in the `<head>` section or `<body>`. I.E: `<script src="yourdir/yourfile.js"></script>`

Comment: I second the advice on developer tools. Viewing the source files as well as the console output should give you some good ideas on what exactly is going wrong, like if the source file is there but isn't running or if it isn't being linked at all to begin with.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, the quickest way to figure out what's going on is to open the JavaScript console by typing Ctrl-Shift-J on Windows or Cmd-Shift-J on Mac.  If it's a syntax problem you'll see it there.  If it's a network problem (like a missing file), you can also look at the "Network" tab to see if anything shows up in red.

Comment: Hmm... alright, it says "failed to load resource file not found" I've downloaded the jquery library and have placed it in the same directory as my html files... should it go instead into the same folder I have my .js files created in?

Comment: So, I'd need to add <script src="jquery-3.2.1/home.js"></script> to the head of my html document then?

Comment: @Sylvia585 What IDE are you using? In many of them, you can just drag the file from the list of files and drop it onto your html file, and the location will be automatically added.

Comment: I'm using Brackets.

Comment: I've managed to just link to the google version using this code:   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> But it's not finding the home.js file I created and added the functions to...